# I don't know the meaning of " this is that"

Tags: meaning

> A: What is this photo about?
>   B:This is that he told me something.

I don't know the meaning of the sentence above.
What is the meaning of the sentence like " This is that he told me something." in this sentence?
 Please, tell me the meaning.

Comment: *This is what he told me.* conveys the purpose. *that..* and ...*something* adds ambiguity.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I am as confused by B as you are.

Comment: @박용현 I think it's better to quote the sentence you found in full. *This is that he told me something* sounds too odd to me, and apparently to others as well.

Comment: @JavaLatte Got it! Let's close this question as a duplicate.